# How to clear a linked list using double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Hi I'm trying to make a function that clears a linked list that `*first` will point to, then the node `**first` should be freed and the pointer `*first` set to `NULL`.

I'm having trouble grasping double pointers and can't get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move to the next list element *before* you delete the node.  Otherwise you are accessing memory that has been freed.

```
while( *first != NULL )
{
    temp = *first;
    *first = temp->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

Be aware that because you're trashing the whole list, `*first` is going to eventually be NULL.  So you can use a single-pointer (just like `temp`) to traverse your list, and then set `*first = NULL` at the end.  That saves an extra pointer indirection, which arguably is wasteful of CPU in this case.

**[edit]** What I mean is:

```
struct node *curr = *first;
struct node *prev;            

while( curr != NULL )
{
    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
    free(prev);
}

*first = NULL;
```

Generally, I find that the less pointer dereferencing you have going on, the easier the code is to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 0):

```
node* remove_node(node **double_pointer,int search_value)
//pass head of your node as a parameter to double pointer
{while(*double_pointer && **(double_pointer).value!=search_value)
{
double_pointer=&((**double_pointer)->next);
}
if(**double_pointer!=null)
{//lines below are to delete the node which contains our search value
node* deleted_node=*double_pointer;
*double_pointer=*double_pointer->next;
return deleted node;
}}
```